# String input error

Tags: c++

Could you please help me determining what is wrong in my code again? Every time you select a case, for example you selected "1" which is "NBA Player", and you are asked who is your favorite player, the program ends as soon as you type your answer. I think the problem is in my getline statement but I can't really identify it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
  int choice;
  string nbaPlayer;
  string tele;
  string food;
  string subject;
  string x;

  cout << "This program determines your favorites.\n\n";
  cout << "Please select the number of your corresponding choice.";
  cout << "\n1. NBA Player";
  cout << "\n2. Teleserye";
  cout << "\n3. Food";
  cout << "\n4. Subject";
  cout << "\n5. Exit";
  cin >> choice;

  switch (choice)
    {

    case 1:
      cout << "You have chosen NBA Player.\n";
      cout << "Please enter your favorite NBA Player. \n";
      getline(cin, nbaPlayer);
      cout << "Your favorite NBA player is " << nbaPlayer;
      break;

    case 2:
      cout << "You have chosen Teleserye.\n";
      cout << "Please enter your favorite teleserye. \n";
      getline(cin, tele);
      cout << "Your favorite teleserye is " << tele;
      break;

    case 3:
      cout << "You have chosen food.\n";
      cout << "Please enter your favorite food. \n";
      getline(cin, food);
      cout << "Your favorite food is " << food;
      break;

    case 4:
      cout << "You have chosen subject.\n";
      cout << "Please enter your favorite subject. \n";
      getline(cin, subject);
      cout << "Your favorite subject is " << subject;
      break;

    case 5:
      cout << "You chose to exit.\n";
      break;

    default:
      cout <<"\nInvalid input";

    }

  getch();
}
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg what I mean is that the getline statement doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Of course it ends, after the `switch` statement there is nothing to continue the program.

You probably want a loop around the output and `switch`:

```
bool go_on = true;

while (go_on)
{
    // Output menu...
    // Get choice

    switch (choice)
    {
        // All other cases...

    case 5:
        go_on = false;  // Tell loop to end
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Oh, it seems that your problem is that you get an empty line... This is because after you get the `choice`, the stream leaves the newline in the input buffer, so when you do `std::getline` it reads that newline and not the input you want.

You can remove the trailing newline like this:

```
std::cin >> choice;

// Skip trailing text, up to and including the newline
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

Comment: I suspect this is what the `getch()` at the end was intended for, but it's in the wrong place.

Comment: @Barmar It seems to very common to use e.g. `getch` at the end to stop the program from exiting until a key is pressed, especially for beginners. And `getch` can't be used for this as it bypasses the stream input and read directly from the console.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I knew it bypassed the stream, but I thought that was just another beginner error.